# Subtracting columns based on greater than in bash

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file with multiple columns:

```
$ cat file.txt
a bc 34 67 
t gh 68 -34
f jh -9 76
h in -66 -14
and so on
```

I am trying to extract when both columns are negative; when both are positive then subtract the two columns based on which value is greater; and if either column negative then add both the columns

For both negative its quite easy:
`less file.txt | egrep -i "\-.*\-" | less`

```
Expected Output:
h in -66 -14
```

For both positive I tried the following to no avail:
`less file.txt | egrep -iv "\-.*\-" | awk '($3>$4 {print $0,($3-$4)}) || ($4>$3 {print $0,($4-$3)})' | less`

```
Expected Output:
a bc 34 67 33
```

For either negative,
`less file.txt | egrep -iv "\-.*\-" | awk '($3<0||$4<0) {print $0,($3+$4)}' | less`

```
Expected Output:
t gh 68 -34 34
f jh -9 76  67
```

I am seeing this error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=3208) fatal: print to "standard output" failed (Broken pipe)
egrep: write error
```

I know its a basic thing to do, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what to do if one, or both, of the values are `=0`?

Comment: Regarding `egrep -i "\-.*\-"` - 1) `egre[p` is deprecated in favor of `-grep -E`, and 2) `-` isn't a regexp metachar except in the context of a bracket expression so you shouldn't be escaping it, 3) `-i` makes  the match case-insensitive but there's no letters in your regexp so that doesn't make sense, 4) you should always use single quotes unless you need double quotes.. So `egrep -i "\-.*\-"` should be written `grep -E '-.*-'` (if you actually needed grep at all which you don't).

Comment: fwiw, if you find yourself using `awk` then you typically don't need to use `(e)grep` nor `less`; `awk` is capable of matching patterns (like `(e)grep`) and reading directly from files (no need for `less`)

Comment: Regarding `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=3208) fatal: print to "standard output" failed (Broken pipe)
egrep: write error` - whatever's causing that, it's not the code you've shown in your question. Maybe a problem in your environment, maybe a problem in the code that calls the code you've shown us, maybe some other code you haven't shown us, maybe something else but it's not THAT code.

Answer (score 2):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
$3<0 && $4<0 { print $0                          ; next }
$3>0 && $4>0 { print $0, ($3>=$4 ? $3-$4 : $4-$3); next }
             { print $0, $3+$4 }
' file.txt
```

**NOTE:** may need to be tweaked if `$3==0` and/or `$4==0` ... depends on OP's requirements for this scenario

This generates:

```
a bc 34 67 33
t gh 68 -34 34
f jh -9 76 67
h in -66 -14
```

Answer (score 1):

Another awk implementation:

```sh
awk '
    function abs(x) {
        if (x < 0) x = -x
        return x
    }
    $3 >= 0 || $4 >= 0 {$(NF+1) = abs(abs($3) - abs($4))} 
    {print}
' file.txt
```

```
a bc 34 67 33
t gh 68 -34 34
f jh -9 76 67
h in -66 -14
```

If you wanted to do this in plain bash:

```sh
abs() { echo $(($1 < 0 ? -($1) : $1)); }

while read -ra fields; do
    a=${fields[2]}
    b=${fields[3]}
    if ((a >= 0 || b >= 0)); then
        fields+=($(abs $(($(abs $a) - $(abs $b)))))
    fi
    echo "${fields[*]}"
done < file.txt
```